# finding cubed root using delta and epsilon in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a program that finds cubed root using delta and epsilon but i'm stuck because i cant figure out why my program runs in an infinite loop

```
    num = 100

    epsilon = 0.01
    guess = num/3.0


    while abs(guess**3 - num) >= epsilon:
        delta = abs(guess**3 - num)/100
        if guess**3 > num:
            guess = (guess - delta)
        if guess**3 < num:
            guess = (guess + delta)
    print("Guess:", guess)
```

Comment: My guess is that your `guess**3 - num` never converges on a value that's less than the `epsilon`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the root of the problem is an incorrect mathematical algorithm.

Comment: The more accurate your guess becomes, your delta get smaller and smaller and will continue adding/substracting lower and lower values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing, you should use `if/elif` instead of separate `if` blocks.

Consider the following:
when `guess**3 > num` is `True`, you update `guess` by reducing its value so that `guess**3 < num` (the next if condition) becomes `True` again, which reverses the initial update. In summary, the value of `guess` is never changed in that loop, and the loop whirls to infinity.

Secondly you want to regularize the `delta` value (penalize it) as it can be come alarming large as the value of `num` increases.

```
num = 100

epsilon = 0.01
guess = num/3.0

while abs(guess**3 - num) >= epsilon:
    delta = abs(guess**3 - num)/num
    if guess**3 > num:
        guess = (guess - delta*epsilon**0.5)
    elif guess**3 < num:
        guess = (guess + delta*epsilon**0.5)
print("Guess:", guess)
```

Comment: Yes, and do not forget about `equality` branch: `guess**3 >= num`

Comment: @EugenKonkov Good observation, but an equality will not require an update on `guess`. Equality will simply stop the while loop when the condition is evaluated at the next iteration.