# How to break out from the Infinite "While" loop? Determining cube root of a problem

Tags: python, while-loop, infinite-loop

Can anyone help me understand why my while loop is resulting in infinite loop? I've checked it with Pythontutor.com, and after the counter exceeds 4, the guess, and y value is not updated (I have checked with both 8 and 27 as the value of x).

```
# Finding the cube root of any number 

user_input = input("Please type an integer to find the cube root of: ")

# Variables declared

x = int(user_input)
y = 0
guess = 10
counter = 0
epsilon = 0.01

# The condition will continue until the difference is equal to or less than epsilon

while abs((guess**3)) - abs(x) > epsilon:
    guess = (guess + (x / guess)) / 2
    y = guess
    counter += 1
    if (abs(guess**3)) - abs(x) == 0:
        print(x, "is a perfect cube, and its square root is ",y)
            
print(x, "is not a perfect cube, and its square root is ",y)    
print(counter)    
print(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar post and you can find the whole explanation there: [finding cubed root using delta and epsilon in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40143166/finding-cubed-root-using-delta-and-epsilon-in-python)

So, this should work:

```
num = 100

epsilon = 0.01
guess = num/3.0

while abs(guess**3 - num) >= epsilon:
    delta = abs(guess**3 - num)/num
    if guess**3 > num:
        guess = (guess - delta*epsilon**0.5)
    elif guess**3 < num:
        guess = (guess + delta*epsilon**0.5)
print("Guess:", guess)
```